# Oracle APEX - what can I use to find references in application to the pages that do not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

There are some pages in the application that have been removed (I do not know the page numbers). How can I find pages in application that reference those missing or deleted pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the **Advisor**.

It is located under "Utilities" for each application. I suggest you have a look at all it says, but *check* you are looking for is named "Referenced Page Number Exists".